# Can't create multiple files using PrintWriter

Tags: java

So I'm writing a really basic program for school that first asks me to create multiple text files.

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(**"lastname//finance.txt, lastname//taxrecords.txt"**);

But when I try and run the program it doesn't even create one of the files and says something is wrong with the bolded parts. When I try and use PrintWriter twice it says the variable is already defined.

Comment: You need to make two variables.

Comment: WHere does it say you can provide two filenames?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use different instances of PrintWriter objects. one instance for each file you want to write in.

```
PrintWriter firstFileWriter = new PrintWriter("lastname//finance.txt");
PrintWriter secondFileWriter = new PrintWriter("lastname//taxrecords.txt");
```

then you could use `firstFileWriter.write("something");` to write in your first file, and `secondFileWriter.write("something else");` to write in second one